# Running a function even when app is in background

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I have a save function that saves values to core data every day at a specific time. But when the app is not running, or is in background - it will of course not save the values.
Is there any way of solving this issue - saving the data whilst the app is running in background?
Here's the function:

```
  func addValueDateToCore() {

// make sure data is not saved twice
    if hasBeen == 0 {

        hasBeen += 1

    let newData: SavedAwayData = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "SavedAwayData", into: DatabaseController.getContext()) as! SavedAwayData

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none

    newData.name = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
    newData.greenCustomer2 = veryHappyCustomer
    newData.orangeCustomer2 = happyCustomer
    newData.redCustomer2 = unHappyCustomer

    DatabaseController.saveContext()
    }


}
```

The hasBeen variable gets mutated to 0 by another function a couple of seconds after addValueDateToCore(), to those of whom might want to comment on that.

Comment: I see no one has helped you out, yet.  Have you tried adding a print statement inside the block to confirm saveContext() is being called? Can you please show the code where you update hasBeen.

Comment: I know that the written down code is working, and the rest of the application as well. Considering the issue written in my question I found an alternative way of solving it.

Comment: Ok. Glad you worked it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps can only run in the background in certain [very specific situations](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW1) like playing audio or handling background network connections. Your question doesn't sound like it fits any of Apple's background modes, but take a look at the docs and see what you think.

A better way (or at least a way that would work on iOS) might be to deal with this when your app launches. Look to see if any days were missed, and fill in the missing data.